# Estimating shift between two images

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I have two images of different resolutions lets say the template image is - 3301 × 2477 (width and height) and test image is - 3507 × 2480 (width x height). The test image is shifted may be by k pixels either to the left or right or top or bottom. I want to reliably find the shift with subpixel accuracy. I have tried multiple approaches the one I am interested is to find the transformation matrix between the template image and test image and use the resulting matrix to estimate the shift.

So I use SIFT with RANSAC to find the point-to-point correspondences between two images and I got the following homography matrix -

```
array([[  1.00134,  -0.00314, 153.47602],
       [ -0.00097,   0.9956 , -15.99202],
       [  0.     ,  -0.     ,   1.     ]])
```

How do I estimate the shift between two images from this matrix?? The [1,3] and [2,3] elements of the matrix are not the correct shifts. The correct shift is around (-9.23 pixels, 0.7 pixels). Note that I have already tried the correlation-based approach the results are not great.

What am I missing here? I have verified the point-to-point correspondences and they look quite good.

Comment: looks like the shift is (153.5, -16).  What is the "correct shift"?

Comment: The correct shift is around (-9.23 pixels, 0.7 pixels)

Comment: [mre] is required. that includes input data.